# How to create a custom EventProcessors in Disruptor?

Tags: java, disruptor-pattern

I am looking to create a custom EventProcessors in Disruptor but the documentation is very minimal. (https://code.google.com/p/disruptor/wiki/DisruptorWizard) How is this done. What are the concepts behind it and what are the issues and pitfalls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is very broad, so is my answer.

- the concept behind the event processor is that it processes one event at a time in a single thread.
- the issue is that you must decompose you system into asynchronous events.
- pitfalls: it may be much more complicated than you need unless you really need millions of events per second. (And this is pretty rare out side HFT)